# Treat one group as two because the rows are separeted

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's suppose I have the data frame

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("a", 5)), 
                 b = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 5), rep(1, 8)))

> df
   a b
1  a 1
2  a 1
3  a 2
4  a 2
5  a 2
6  b 2
7  b 2
8  b 1
9  b 1
10 b 1
11 a 1
12 a 1
13 a 1
14 a 1
15 a 1
```

I would like to group the data by `a` and `b` and name the group (numerate) in the third column but I the new group for me is the group with values other that the group above. So I have group `a1`, `a2` `b2`, `b1`, and again `a1`. I would like to treat the second `a1` as new group. So, the result should be:

```
   a b group
1  a 1 1
2  a 1 1
3  a 2 2
4  a 2 2
5  a 2 2
6  b 2 3
7  b 2 3
8  b 1 4
9  b 1 4
10 b 1 4
11 a 1 5
12 a 1 5
13 a 1 5
14 a 1 5
15 a 1 5
```

The only way I can do it is to use loop:

```
group <- numeric(nrow(df))
value <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (i == 1) {
        group[i] <- value
    } else {
        if (all(df$a[i] == df$a[i - 1], 
                df$b[i] == df$b[i - 1])) {
            group[i] <- value
        } else {
            value <- value + 1
            group[i] <- value
        }
    }
}
df$group <- group
df
```

But this solution is not very smart. Can I do something like that using `dplyr` or without loop?

Comment: In base R `df$group <- cumsum(c(1, abs(diff(df$b)) + abs(diff(as.integer(df$a)))))` will work for your example. If both a and b change at once, this will break, but you can fix it with `pmin` like `cumsum(c(1, pmin(abs(diff(df$b)) + abs(diff(as.integer(df$a))), 1)))`.

Comment: A data.table approach would be `dt[, id := .GRP, by = .(rleid(a), rleid(b))]`, another base R could be `with(rle(as.character(interaction(as.character(df$a), df$b))), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus  `rleid` can take multiple columns `setDT(df)[, id := .GRP, by = .(rleid(a, b))]`

Comment: Anybody care to answer this?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("a", 5)), 
                 b = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 5), rep(1, 8)))

library(dplyr)
transmute(df,a,b,group=cumsum(ifelse(lag(a)!=a | lag(b)!=b | is.na(lag(a)),1,0)))
```

Or:

```
mutate(df,group=cumsum(ifelse(lag(a)!=a | lag(b)!=b | is.na(lag(a)),1,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `unite` in `tidyr` and `rle`:

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)
df%>%
unite("a_b",a,b,remove=FALSE)%>%
mutate(group = {sq = rle(a_b); rep(seq_along(sq$lengths), sq$lengths)})

   a_b a b group
1  a_1 a 1     1
2  a_1 a 1     1
3  a_2 a 2     2
4  a_2 a 2     2
5  a_2 a 2     2
6  b_2 b 2     3
7  b_2 b 2     3
8  b_1 b 1     4
9  b_1 b 1     4
10 b_1 b 1     4
11 a_1 a 1     5
12 a_1 a 1     5
13 a_1 a 1     5
14 a_1 a 1     5
15 a_1 a 1     5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::group_indices` to get a sequence of group ids

```
gi <- group_indices(df, a, b)
gi
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1
```

and then just add to these group ids their cummax

```
ids <- cummax(gi) + gi
ids 
# [1] 2 2 4 4 4 8 8 7 7 7 5 5 5 5 5
```

They are not exactly like in your desired output but can be relabelled if necessary. They will work as group indices either way.